# PHP cURL not being allowed?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to scrape a page with the use of cURL but all of my attempts doesn't work.

Here's my code:

#### PHP

```
public function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $loc = null;
    if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $data, $r)) {
        $loc = trim($r[1]);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($loc);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();

    return $data;
}
```

The response I get by running that is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 20:29:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d6f3effa0b8c33cd8092e9f003d5c751c1482956968; expires=Thu, 28-Dec-17 20:29:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.thedomaintoscrape.com; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Refresh: 8;URL=/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?pass=1482956972.162-3LFzqX3Gdh
Cache-Control: no-cache
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3187c3bb054a551c-ORD
```

I don't really know what to make of it as I don't understand what the problem is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Some websites use methods to make it impossible, or at least very difficult to scrape. Looks like that site wants to use cookies and is checking the referral URL to see if it's local..  Google "php curl cookies"  and "php curl set referer"

Comment: Without knowing anything more, I'd probably choose to take `Service Temporarily Unavailable` at face value.